# In Unity, how can I register a custom file type that is always opened with my game?

Tags: unity, windows, loading, file-format, operating-system

I want my players to be able to create their own scenes as custom levels, save them as files (say `custom1.gamelevel`), and open them directly in my game program by double-clicking the level file, rather than having to go through the steps of opening the game, browsing to the file in my menus, and then loading that scene/level.

I already have loading custom levels covered. I just need a way to associate this custom file type with my game which can open it.

I am mainly interested in a Windows-based solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hmm, would a combination of [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/138715/read-command-line-arguments.html) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/406985/programatically-associate-file-extensions-with-application-on-windows) do the trick? (I did not try it. I hope it is a starting point for you.)

Comment: Thanks I'll look at these and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't explicitly a problem of Unity. This is something an installer could do for your programm.

Summed up: it is a registry setting

Hope this link helps:

[where-in-the-registry-does-windows-store-with-which-program-to-open-certain-files @ superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/266268/where-in-the-registry-does-windows-store-with-which-program-to-open-certain-fil)

[Code samples on microsoft social network](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I was thinking this might be the direction I'd have to take. I'll look over the links you've posted here and give it a shot.